# UH1 fin under chin bubble

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, airframe

What is the purpose of the fin under the nose. It’s close to the co pilot side and starts at the bottom of the battery compartment and ends Near the bottom of the chin bubble.

[Wikipedia Photo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:U.S._Air_Force_TH-1_Huey.JPG)
[image]

Comment: @757toga, I don't think the ring is actually part of the fin being asked about though, because you can see the same paired ring on the near side.  I think it's just the perspective that makes it look like part of the fin assembly.

Answer (score -2):

It’s a wire strike protection system.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_strike_protection_system

Comment: The question is about the “fin” that is flush with the bottom, not the wire cutter sticking out an angle.

Comment: I added another picture trying to remove the wire strike system so it’s not as confusing

Comment: Then I don’t think “fin” is a good choice of words, because I think shark fin, and also went right to the forward angled protuberance. The scribbles don’t help, neither does the same view highlighting the forward angled bit.  If what you are looking for is what is in the third photo, I recommend simply deleting the others.  They do nothing but add confusion.

Comment: Ok the other two pictures are gone. Mr hall the picture that is still there, do you know what that is for?

Comment: Anthony, unfortunately I do not, otherwise I'd answer.  But... when I first read it I was about to post this same answer because I too looked at the "wrong" part in the first photo.  Thanks for clearing it up, hopefully somebody will know.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feed back, if you need up finding it out please let me know. I will try to get a better picture Tuesday and put it on here.

Comment: My guess is that the ring hoist/attachment at the aft end of the "fin," while being used, will have a cable attached to it. The fin is there to deflect the cable (when/if swaying) so that the other attachments, antennas. wire cutter, etc. on the bottom of the helicopter are not damaged.